# Adding a shadow to Sliding Drawer

Tags: android, shadow, slidingdrawer

I knew Sliding Drawer is deprecated. So I imported Sliding Drawer Class to my own package and I customized it to satisfy my requirements. Now the scenario is, I want to add a shadow that wraps both handle and content of the sliding drawer. If I add shadow for handle and content separately (by giving image with shadow as background for both handle and content),then the shadow makes a gap between the handle and content. That is not my requirement. Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.someDrawable,GravityCompat.Start);
```

You will need to use a drawable for the shadow. Use the setDrawerShadow method on the navigationDrawer object.